# React update state of a button based on another button

Tags: reactjs, button, state

For this project I am currently working on, I need to highlight the button that was clicked on each layer/row. However, the way I have right now it highlights every button that was clicked.

I need something like this:

[correct highlighted path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ufzc.png)

But then when I click on the same row, it does not remove the highlight from the button that I pressed before. How can I update and reset the state of the previous button that was clicked? I tried to use the useRef hook for this but I haven't been successful so far.

[wrong highlighted path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSeQ7.png)

**EDIT: Added code**

This is the code that I have for the component of each row in the website:

```
function StackRow({ data, partition, level, index, onClick, getInfo, isApp }) {
  const classes = useStyles({ level: level });

  const rowRef = useRef();

  const handleSelectedButtons = (flag, setFlag, btnRef) => {
    console.log(rowRef);
  };

  return (
    <Card
      key={partition + '_' + index + '_' + level}
      className={classes.card}
      id={level}
      ref={rowRef}
    >
      {data.map((field) => {
        return (
          <StackItem
            key={partition + '_' + field[0] + '_' + level}
            data={field[0]}
            info={field[1]}
            level={level}
            onClick={onClick}
            getInfo={getInfo}
            isApp={isApp}
            handleSelectedButtons={handleSelectedButtons}
            rowRef={rowRef}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Card>
  );
}
```

And this is the code I have for each button of the row:

```
function StackItem({
  data,
  info,
  level,
  onClick,
  getInfo,
  isApp,
  handleSelectedButtons,
}) {
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

  const btnRef = useRef();

  const styleProps = {
    backgroundColor: flag ? '#06d6a0' : level % 2 === 0 ? '#22223b' : '#335c67',
  };

  const classes = useStyles(styleProps);

  return (
    <Button
      ref={btnRef}
      isselected={flag.toString()}
      key={data}
      className={classes.button}
      variant="outlined"
      onClick={(event) => {
        onClick(event, setFlag, btnRef);
        handleSelectedButtons(flag, setFlag, btnRef);
        getInfo(info, level, isApp);
      }}
      disableElevation={true}
    >
      {data}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

There are some useless variables and states there because I have been trying all sort of stuff to do this.

**EDIT: Added data sample & project structure**

Data looks like:

```
{
  application: {
    cmake: {
      info: str,
      versions: {
        version_no: {
          application: {...}
        }
      }
    },
    gcc: {...},
    git: {...},
    intel: {...},
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

The structure of the project is like:

```
App
 L Stack
    L StackRow
          L StackItem
```

Where App is the entire application, Stack is the container for everything in the images apart from the search box, StackRow matches one row of the Stack, and StackItem is one item/button from the StackRow.

**EDIT: Added Stack component**

```
function Stack({ data, partition, getInfo }) {
  const [level, setLevel] = useState(0);
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [isApp, setIsApp] = useState(true);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [prevLevel, setPrevLevel] = useState(-1);

  const cardsRef = useRef();

  const handleClick = (event, setFlag, btnRef) => {
    let rows = cardsRef.current.childNodes;
    let currBtn = event.target.innerText;

    let curr;
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      let rowItems = rows[i].childNodes;
      for (let j = 0; j < rowItems.length; j++) {
        if (currBtn === rowItems[j].textContent) {
          curr = rowItems[j].parentElement;
        }
      }
    }

    let id;
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      if (curr.textContent === rows[i].textContent) {
        id = i;
      }
    }

    if (level === id) {
      if (id % 2 === 0) {
        setIsApp(true);
        if (selected.length === 0) {
          setSelected([...selected, data[currBtn].versions]);
        } else {
          let lastSelected = selected[selected.length - 1];
          setSelected([...selected, lastSelected[currBtn].versions]);
        }
      } else {
        let lastSelected = selected[selected.length - 1];
        setSelected([...selected, lastSelected[currBtn].child]);
        setIsApp(false);
      }
      setPrevLevel(level);
      setLevel(level + 1);
    } else {
      let newSelected = selected.slice(0, id);
      if (id % 2 === 0) {
        setIsApp(true);
        if (newSelected.length === 0) {
          setSelected([...newSelected, data[currBtn].versions]);
        } else {
          let lastSelected = newSelected[newSelected.length - 1];
          setSelected([...newSelected, lastSelected[currBtn].versions]);
        }
      } else {
        let lastSelected = newSelected[newSelected.length - 1];
        setSelected([...newSelected, lastSelected[currBtn].child]);
        setIsApp(false);
      }
      setPrevLevel(level);
      setLevel(id + 1);
    }
    setFlag(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let fields = [];
    let lastSelected = selected[selected.length - 1];
    if (level % 2 !== 0) {
      fields = Object.keys(lastSelected).map((key) => {
        let path = lastSelected[key].path;
        let module = lastSelected[key].module_name;
        let info = 'module: ' + module + ' path: ' + path;
        return [key, info];
      });
    } else {
      if (selected.length !== 0)
        fields = Object.keys(lastSelected).map((key) => {
          let info = lastSelected[key].info;
          return [key, info];
        });
    }
    if (fields.length > 0) {
      if (level > prevLevel) {
        setCards((prevState) => [...prevState, fields]);
      } else {
        setCards((prevState) => [
          ...prevState.slice(0, selected.length),
          fields,
        ]);
      }
    }
  }, [selected, level, prevLevel]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let fields = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
      let info = data[key].info;
      return [key, info];
    });
    setCards([fields]);
    setLevel(0);
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLevel(0);
    setPrevLevel(-1);
    setSelected([]);
  }, [partition]);

  if (cards) {
    return (
      <div ref={cardsRef}>
        {cards.map((card, index) => (
          <StackRow
            data={card}
            partition={partition}
            level={index}
            index={cards.indexOf(card)}
            onClick={handleClick}
            getInfo={getInfo}
            isApp={isApp}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  } else return null;
}
```

**EDIT: Added data sample**

```
{
  cmake: {
    info: "A cross-platform, open-source build system. CMake is a family of tools designed to build, test and package software.",
    versions: {
      "3.17.3": {
         child: {},
         module_name: "cmake/3.17.3",
         path: "/opt/apps/nfs/spack/var/spack/environments/matador/modules/linux-centos8-x86_64/Core/cmake/3.17.3.lua",
         version_no: "3.17.3"
       }
    }
  },
  gcc: {
    info: "...",
    versions: {
      "8.4.0": {
         child: {
           cmake: {...},
           cuda: {...},
           cudnn: {...},
           openmpi: {...},
           .
           .
           .
         },
         module_name: "...",
         path: "...",
         version_no: "..."
       }
      "9.3.0": {...},
      "10.1.0": {...}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use refs, lift state up here, the `flag` for a selected button should be state in your parent component, it should not be state in the child component. If you lift state up, you'll find a lot of this stuff feels more natural - data just flows down through your tree.

Comment: But then how do I pass for example 'false' to one of the buttons and 'true' to another? In this case, removing the previous 'true' state of the button and updating the new one? It makes sense to keep only the variable at the 'row' level because it is in fact only for the row, not for each child button, but I am not sure how to update the buttons then

Comment: Can you show us what a sample of your data looks like? Also, what's your topmost component that receives your data in your code? Things like `data`, `level`, `partition`, and `index` - it's not clear what any of these are

Comment: `data` is the actual data that I get at the `App` component and pass it down the tree doing some filtering. `level` is the number of 'rows'. `partition` is something else that I use to filter the data with tabs in the website. `index` is the index of the button in the array that I just pass it to give it to the `key` prop

Comment: You can see that you haven't shown your `Stack` component - where **all** the state should be living. No state in `StackRow` and no state in `StackItem`. `StackRow` and `StackItem` should only accept props and hold no state themselves.

Comment: Just added it as well! You can see that it manages all the states, just not the `flag` state which is in the `StackItem`. The refs I was just using to test to see if it would work, they are non-essential. Sorry if it is somehow a mess, I am new to React and have been trying to learn all by myself.

Comment: That's ok, it's obvious you are learning - people tend to "overcomplicate" react when they are new to it as you have done because they still think imperatively rather than declaratively. This is 100% normal and probably the most common way to start out. One final question is could you post a "full" example of your data - even if it's just for the cmake application. Once I see the full data structure, I'll provide you an example of how this could be handled cleanly in react.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Adam, you are very kind! I have just added the sample data. The way it works is that some applications, e.g. `gcc`, will some some versions, and with the application/version it is used to "build" other applications, that go inside the `child` object, which in the case of `cmake` is empty because no application was built/created using `cmake` in this case, but for the other options like `gcc` there are many other apps with their corresponding versions. And it goes on for the last apps as well, possibly having other child apps...

Comment: Are the child apps located in the `child` object? I'd like to see one nested more than one level

Comment: Yes, they are located inside the `child` object. I will add a nested example!

Comment: As you can see, the other applications are inside the `child` component, and their structure is just as their parent, for example `cuda` in `gcc` will also have `info` and `versions` and so on.

Comment: I have moved the `flag` state from `<StackItem />` to `<Stack />` as mentioned, thus neither `<StackRow />` nor `<StackItem />` have states. However, when I click on a button right now all the buttons change their colors. Understandably because of the logic I have on the handleClick function on `<Stack />`. What I really do not know is how to pass the value to only the button that I clicked and to remove the highlight of the other possible buttons that were clicked in the same row. Is it possible to uniquely identify the button?

Comment: We'll end up with a recursive component structure - you can't work with this type of data without one. Sorry I haven't gotten back to this yet, I will, but I probably wouldn't try to work with what you already have.

Comment: So do you think there is no way to achieve this with the project and data structure that I have currently?

Comment: I'm not saying this will serve all your needs, but it will hopefully give you an idea: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4ngvul?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam, that actually helped a lot! I was thinking about the problem in a completely different way and this helped me view it in a new light. Thank you so much!